# communication between winsock and java socket

Tags: java, c++, sockets, winsock

I'm trying to build a client/server application with a `java server` on the one and a `c++ client` on the other side.

Client:

```
while(true)
    {
        sock = con.connectToServer(argv[2], port);

        if(sock!=NULL)
        {
            _itoa_s(clientID,sendBuffer,16,10);
            send(sock,sendBuffer,strlen(sendBuffer),0);

            printf("waiting for response\n");

            bytes = recv(sock,recvBuffer,sizeof(recvBuffer)-1,0);
            recvBuffer[bytes] = '\0';

            printf("%s",recvBuffer);

            closesocket(sock);
        }

        Sleep(3000);
    }
```

Server Thread:

```
public void run()
    {
        try{
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            out = new BufferedWriter (new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));

            int signID = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
            System.out.println("signID: " + signID);

            //Precessing DataRequest for specific TrafficSign here

            clientSocket.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Exception in TrafficSignServerThread -> " + ex.toString());
        }
    }
```

The problem is, after the successfull connect, the server hang up at the `in.ReadLine()` although the `send()` function returns with 1, which means sending the data was successfull.

If i remove the `recv()` part of the client everything works correctly. So it seems only the combination of `send()` and `recv()` causes the problem.

Comment: Note that this isn't necessarily 'communication between Winsock and Java sockets'. On Windows, every socket is a Winsock socket, including the Java ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common mistake when using readLine() is to forget to send *a line of text*

I would check you sent a newline. e.g. `\n`